# proper cacti installation

Tags: statistics, cacti

I was trying to set up cacti for my ubuntu 10.10 server.

Problem is that there is no images in cacti when accessed.

Uploaded, set up database but there is error if I launch pull.php from ssh:

```
ERROR: creating '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_users_6.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: mmaping file '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_users_6.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: creating '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_load_1min_5.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: mmaping file '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_load_1min_5.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: creating '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_mem_swap_4.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: mmaping file '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_mem_swap_4.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: creating '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_mem_buffers_3.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: mmaping file '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_mem_buffers_3.rrd': Invalid argument
ERROR: creating '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_proc_7.rrd': Invalid argument
07/16/2011 06:29:07 PM - SYSTEM STATS: Time:1.2707 Method:cmd.php Processes:1 Threads:N/A Hosts:2 HostsPerProcess:2 DataSources:5 RRDsProcessed:5
ERROR: mmaping file '/mnt/laptopshop/cacti/rra/localhost_proc_7.rrd': Invalid argument
```

I was trying to google for it but nothing good. So any ideas?